# an error of unauthorized access only appear on my hyperlink but when i try opening it from the browser it opens

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyPareser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request"); //make http to external server external api

const app = express();

app.use(bodyPareser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  //the url is from bitcoin avergae to get the info about price of bitcoin
  var post = req.body.crypto;
  var fiat = req.body.fiat;

  var link = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/";
  finalLink = link + post + fiat; //concatenate the link with the chossen fiat and crypto
  console.log(finalLink);
  request(finalLink, function(error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body); //turn json to js
    var price = data.last; //get the last from the element of the body

    var currentDate = data.display_timestamp;

    res.write("<p>The current date is " + currentDate + "</p>");
    res.write("<h1>The price of " + post + "is " + price + fiat + "</h1>");
    req.send();

  });
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("port set at 3000");
})
```

*an error of unauthorized access only appear on my hyperlink but when i try opening it from the browser it opens
//so what can i change to make this api accessible

Comment: I tried the link in your code . But it is not opening in browser

Comment: the strange thing if u refreshed it one or 2 more times it will open and also if u check the source code it sends 200 so accepted process

Comment: Can you share the link in comment

Comment: https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD

Comment: Did you check the value of finalLink variable

Comment: yes it is the same i checked it by consol.log on the  hyper link

Comment: Try copy and paste the link from browser and check whether it is opening.

Comment: yes it is openning